# Excel Syntax Greater and Less than

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some specific data that I need to group based on counts of 24. I was trying to use the IFS function in excel to do this.

The output Im after is simply if it is 24 or less then 1, between 24 and 48 then 2 and If is it greater than 48 = 3.

The below is a far as I have gotten with the code, I cant seem to get past it. Thanks in advance

```
=IFS(A2<=24,1,AND(A2>24,A2<=48,2,),AND(A2>48,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=IF(A2<=24,1,IF(A2<=48,2,3))

To be honest I'd just do it this way, it just checks if its less than or equal to 24, or greater than or equal to 48 - everything else will be greater than 48 and return a 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your brackets were in the wrong place

```
=IFS(A2<=24,1,AND(A2>24,A2<=48),2,A2>48,3)
```

The [syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) is

> =IFS([Something is True1, Value if True1,Something is True2,Value if True2,Something is True3,Value if True3)

I wonder if you need the AND though. I don't have IFS so can't test.